# Performance Tests in WebAssembler.NET

Tags: performance-testing

I am trying to do some performance and stress test on an web application which is built in WebAssembler.NET and SQL Server 2016.

I have tried several tools but with no results. Can you suggest any tool if anyone has work with this technologies.

Best,

Comment: What tools, what problems with getting results?

Answer (score 0):

Any performance testing tool should work if it is a web-application. Web-application Performance Testing tools generate HTTP requests. It is a standard, or else each web-application would use its own browser.

So, for [black-box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing) performance testing the underlying technology should not matter.

A common performance testing tool is [jMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) which is well documented.

- Start the application
- Execute the load tests
- Monitor the servers
- Analyse the data